# How do I manage SDF databases remotely?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-ce

This is a silly question but I can't seem to get a clear idea.

SQL Server CE 4 does not require SQL. So once I copy my .SDF file to my web host, I want to continue making changes only to the remote version and not locally. With a SQL database I would have a connection string and do my thing.

Is it exactly the same with an SDF file? Do I attach them to my SQL Express server to make changes?

Comment: basically how do I open a sqlce4 SDF file ? I tried to connect in SSMS 2008R2 to no avail.. it asks for a password but I never gave it a password

Comment: To open SQLCE 4.0 files locally, you need either: VS 2010 SP1 with SQL Server Compact 4 tools, WebMatrix, http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com or another 3rd party product http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html

Comment: http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/ seems to be good be we use EXPRESS version of vs at work :(

Comment: There is a standalone version available, please vote if you would like it updated (but it works) - http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/50225

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only open SQL Compact files locally. If you have access to a command prompt on your host machine, you can use my command line utility: http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com

Comment: But how can I run scripts that are created with the entity designer?  Can I run them in vs2010 sp1?  it seems to not work the same as query window in ssms2008r2 ?